# Bulk deleting from extension's localstorage by value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using `localstorage` to track domain visits and their timestamp.

Here's how I'm setting it:

```
localStorage.setItem(`${domain[0]}`, JSON.stringify(Date.now()));
```

What code would I use to delete all rows with a timestamp that's older than 30 days so users don't end up with too much extra data that probably won't be used?

I've seen a lot of examples about deleting individual rows based on the key.  But I can't find anything related to bulk deleting based upon the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate all key/value pairs explicitly:

```
const cutOff = Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
Object.entries(localStorage).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  const time = JSON.parse(v);
  if (time < cutOff) {
    delete localStorage[k];
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a "best practice" for when this should be run or a way to control that?  For example, should it just be put in the background script and let it do it's thing?  Or be setup to just run once per day?

Comment: Once a day sounds fine. You can use chrome.alarms API for that or store the last cleanup's date in a separate key in localStorage.